# hyperlink cell elements passed in a Flex datagrid

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I'm trying to render a Flex datagrid using an external XML datasource. Is there a way I can specify in the XML that a cell element should appear as a hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a datarenderer for a specified column that is called "html" and then style the content of that column. If you XML has a

```
<html>http://www.google.com</html>
```

you can get this value in the datarenderer with

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;    
            }

<mx:button label="{data.html}" 
      click="{navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.google.com'), '_self');}"/>
```

I hope this helps